# jQuery append() only working first time

Tags: jquery, append

Strange issue. I've got the following code:

```
// remove template row from DOM and store in variable

var $addDegreeRow = $('.addDegreeRow').remove();
$('#addDegreeLink').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.degreeSection').append($addDegreeRow);
});
```

I'm selecting an element from the DOM, removing it, and preserving its content in a selector `$addDegreeRow`. Then I'm assigning a click event to a link on the page that appends the stored selector to an existing div on the page.

The first time I through the click event everything works perfectly. But the second time through nothing gets appended. And if I look at the HTML in firebug, the `.degreeSection` div gets highlighted each time I perform the click, even if nothing else is being appended. It's like jQuery is overwriting the old `$addDegreeRow` append with the new one, instead of just adding another one.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You are appending the same element again and again. If you want a copy of that element, you have to clone() it first.

Comment: so `.append($addDegreeRow.clone())`?

Comment: @Mega Matt, if that answer worked for you, and was helpful, perhaps you could consider accepting it?

Comment: was reading an element from string, didn't think it needed clone, and there I was, wrong

Comment: @RichardMuvirimi People are still using jQuery?

Comment: @AndreKR WordPress, there is no going around that.